# Refreshing select after selected option is changed by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm updating the selected option programmatically using jQuery, but nothing changes in the browser.  (That is, the old selected option remains selected instead of switching to the newly selected option.)  Suggestions?

Thanks.  --Jeff

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="" action="">
<p>Assign: 
<select name="assigner" id="assigner">
<option value="Sam" selected="selected">Sam</option>
  <option value="Harry">Harry</option>
  <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="Submit" />
</p>
<p>    Task A: <select name="assignment[]" id="assigner">
  <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
  <option value="Harry" selected="selected">Harry</option>
  <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>    
Task B: <select name="assignment[]" id="assigner">
  <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
  <option value="Harry"  selected="selected">Harry</option>
  <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
</select>
</p>
</form></div>
```

and my jQuery code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
$('[name="button1"]').click(
    function(){
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        var assigned = form.find(':selected').first().val();
        form.find(':selected').each(function(index){
            $(this).val( assigned ).change();
        });
    }
 );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm updating the selected option programmatically using jQuery

Not as far as I can see. You're re-setting the value of the selected `option`, but not doing anything as far as I can tell to the actual `select` box.

To change a `select` box, you need to identify it, then call `val` on **it**, not one of its `option` elements.

I can't make out what you want your `input[name="button1"]` to do, but here's an example of updating a `select` box: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/awakec) | [source](http://jsbin.com/awakec/edit)

HTML:

```
<select id="theSelect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Click me">
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    $("#theSelect").val("2");
  });

});
```

---

Separately, as j08691 pointed out in the comments, you can't assign the same `id` value (`"assigner"`) to more than one element. [`id` values **must** be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) in the document. Your code doesn't show you using that `id`, so this may well be unrelated, but it's worth flagging up.

Comment: My form is generated from a database query, so I won't necessarily know the ID's of the select boxes (or even how many will appear in the form).  In addition, there are multiple forms (all similarly structured) on each page.  What I'm trying to do is to allow the user to update all the SELECT boxes on a form with the selected option from the first select box.  So, user assigns Harry to all tasks by selecting Harry in first select box and submitting.  What I really need, I guess, is a way to select all the SELECT boxes which appear on the same form as the button which is clicked.

Comment: @jalperin: *"What I really need, I guess, is a way to select all the SELECT boxes which appear on the same form as the button which is clicked."* `$(this).closest('form').find('select')` would do it, from within an event handler on the button. `$(this)` wraps the button in a jQuery object. `closest('form')` returns a jQuery object for the closest `form` element in the hierarchy. Then `find('select')` finds all `select` elements within that form.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="" action="">
    <p>Assign: 
        <select name="assigner" id="assigner">
            <option value="Sam" selected="selected">Sam</option>
            <option value="Harry">Harry</option>
            <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Task A: <select name="assignment[]" id="assigner2">
            <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
            <option value="Harry" selected="selected">Harry</option>
            <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>    
        Task B: <select name="assignment[]" id="assigner3">
            <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
            <option value="Harry"  selected="selected">Harry</option>
            <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
$('[name="button1"]').click(
    function(){
        var assigned = $("#assigner").val();
        $('#form1 select').val( assigned );
    }
 );
});
</script>
```